# Python script with mysql to exe

Tags: python

Can anyone please help me with how to make python executable file. I have used pyinstaller but it when i run it generates error message that says `Fatal error. Unable to run the script`

I tried pyinstaller with a demo gui and it works but with my it doesn't.
In my code I have used these libraries `reportlab`, `mysql`. Is this making any difference? How can i solve this?

Update from here:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Project.py'],
             pathex=['G:\\Python\\Desktop Python'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Project',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

The above code is the spec file.

Comment: There are probably binary dependencies of some of your library modules, that `pyinstaller` can't find without your help. The documentation has extensive advice about this. Have you tried it? If so, put your `.spec` file in the question.

Comment: Which command did you execute using pyinstaller? Which python version are you using? Are you using anaconda or any other virtual environment?

Comment: @BoarGules I have updated my que

Comment: Hi @Prasad  I've used ```pyinstaller.exe --onefile -w Project.py```. I have tried by removing ```-w```. I'm using python version 3.7

Comment: @RawNewton, you can  add `--debug` parameter in your pyinstaller command and check full stack of errors to know why it is failing to run the script.

Comment: Both `mysql` and `pillow` (used by `reportlab`) have binary extensions (DLLs) but these are not mentioned in `Analysis` so it's likely that your `exe` is failing because it can't find them to load.